# Excel find average of column for each X rows of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large dataset filled with multiple data points. I've included a picture which consists of the following:

```
    column A = IDs
    column B = Colors 
    column C = Data points need to average
```

[image: picture for example]

I need the **average of only the first 2 rows** of data (column C) where the ID (column A) = 1 and the color (column B) = Red. Then I would need the average of the next 2 rows of data with the same criteria. Then I would do the same to find the average where ID = 1 and Color = Blue. Then I would do the same where ID = 2 and Color = Red.

Normally I would do an averageifs formula but since I only need the first X rows of data to be averaged then I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. One additional caveat is that not every ID has an equal number of data points. So ID 1 Color Red could have 4 data points while ID 2 Color Blue could have 6 data points. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to keep averaging pairwise until all data points for each ID/Color group have been calculated?  Will the count of a given ID/Color group always be even?

Comment: So would the first result be 2.75 (rows 2 & 4), and the second result be 2.2 (rows 6 & 8)?  Third result = 2.25 (rows 3 & 5)?

Comment: @RajeshS, see my comment above asking the OP for verification.  That would seem to be the only interpretation consistent with the wording (which is a bit unclear).

Comment: @fixer1234,, by mistake i've posted the comment here,, now please read below my solution next to yours between us.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Iliana, for the clarification.  The key to solving your problem is to (figuratively) divide your data up into groups of four rows.  Then a formula can average the two values for each color in that group.

You've explained that a given ID could have 7 to 10 rows of data. So not all groups will have four rows.  The following approach uses a helper column to designate groups of four (or fewer) rows for each ID.

The table below has 7,8,9 and 10 rows, respectively, for the four ID's shown, and this formula, filled down from D2 in the table below, divides the data for each ID into groups of 4 or less, and designates the groups with a number from 0 to 2:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>8,2,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>4,1,0))`

This formula counts the number of occurrences of each ID as it is filled down.  If the count is > 8, it sets the helper to 2. If the count is > 4, the helper is set to 1.  If the count is 4 or less, the helper is set to 0.

[image]

Now the averages can easily be calculated.  This formula gives the average of the outcome values for each unique ID, Color, and Helper combination:

`=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$35,A$2:A$35,A2,B$2:B$35,B2,D$2:D$35,D2)`

Finally, duplicate values can be eliminated with a little extra effort.  This formula counts the number of ID/Helper combinations in a range that "grows" as the formula is filled down.  If the count is 3 or more, a blank is returned instead of the average.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(D$2:D2,D2,A$2:A2,A2)<3, AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$35,A$2:A$35,A2,B$2:B$35,B2,D$2:D$35,D2),"")`

Thank you again for clearly explaining what you are trying to accomplish.  I hope you find this helpful.  Best of luck.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen the formula used for the int column before. Can you explain how this works? I tried searching but didn't find anything.   In answer to your questions: 1) No, there will not always be an even number 2) 7-10 datapoints for each combinations 3) If the helper column works then I am fine leaving it there. 4) Duplicate averages are okay

Answer (score -1):

*You can use a combination of the SUMIFS and COUNTIFS function to calculate AVERAGE for the pairs of ID and Colour in terms of creating Data Points(Match Rows), where COUNTIFS creates Data Point*

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C17,A2:A17,"1",B2:B17,"RED")/COUNTIFS(A2:A17,"1",B2:B17,"RED")


=SUMIFS(C2:C17,A2:A17,"1",B2:B17,"BLUE")/COUNTIFS(A2:A17,"1",B2:B17,"BLUE")


=SUMIFS(C2:C17,A2:A17,"2",B2:B17,"RED")/COUNTIFS(A2:A17,"2",B2:B17,"RED")
```

*I hope this help you.*

Comment: This doesn't do what was asked in the question.

Comment: @fixer1234,, this is the best possible method to create Data point using Countifs to Calculate Average. Suggest if any other method is in your mind.

Comment: The question is about pairs of rows.  Your approach calculates all qualifying rows (e.g., 4 rows for "1" & "red" rather than two separate results).

Comment: @fixer1234,, yes I know,, but you look first two Rows had common ID but 2 different colours, and colours are in alternation, so it doesn't make any scene to calculate Average. What do you think,,, am I correct?

Comment: @RajeshS I appreciate the answer but it does not answer my problem. The problem is I need the first 2 rows of data for ID = 1 Color = Red and then I need the next 2 rows of data for ID = 1 Color = Red. I want this separated but I'm not sure if there's an excel formula for this which worries me since I have so many rows of data. :s

Comment: Tell me one thing,, you need First Two Rows which have similar ID "1" but not the COLOUR, one is RED other is BLUE and your requirement is, First Tow Rows with ID = "1" and Colour = "RED", which doesn't match the OP. Or you are thinking to pair Row 2 with Row 4 and Row 6 with 8 and so on !!